# Проблема с hover эффектом или хз чем

Tags: html, css, jquery

[Есть сайт](http://mytrueblog.site/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9/)

на нем я делаю уже вторую секцию с раскрывающимися текстами(Развернуть-Свернуть)
первая секция работает нормально, сегодня сделал вторую стили полностью скопировал с первой, но появился какой-то дрянной hover эффект, ну т.е эффект то старый, он есть и в первой секции, но этот эффект как будто режет текст overflow: hidden или меняет высоту блока развернутой карточки, не понимаю как он это делает и откуда берется...

```
.details
  &-block
    display: flex
    &__card
      position: relative
      height: 360px
      &-text
        display: table
        margin: 0 auto
        p
          +reg
          font-size: 14px
          max-width: 436px
          display: block
          text-align: center
        div
          display: none
        ol
          font-size: 14px
        ul
          font-size: 14px
      &-title
        text-align: center
        font-size: 22px
      &-open
        position: absolute
        bottom: 0px
        left: 50%
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
        display: inline-block
        +reg
        color: #6FAD69
        border-bottom: 1px solid #6FAD69
      &-close
        display: table
        margin: 0 auto
        +reg
        color: #6FAD69
        border-bottom: 1px solid #6FAD69
      &-img
        position: relative
        img
          display: block
          margin: 0 auto
      &:hover
        cursor: pointer
        background-color: lighten(#6FAD69, 10%)
        h1
          color: #fff
          text-decoration: underline
        p
          color: #fff
        ol
          color: #fff
        ul
          color: #fff
        a
          color: #fff
    &__card:first-child
      flex-basis: 33%
      margin-bottom: 30px
    &__card:nth-child(2)      
      flex-basis: 33%
    &__card:nth-child(3)      
      flex-basis: 33%
```

```
    <section class="details">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="details-block">
          <div class="details-block__card">
            <h1 class="details-block__card-title">Фундамент дома</h1>
            <!-- /.details-block__card-title -->
            <div class="details-block__card-img">
              <img src="img/details/img-1.jpg" alt="img-1">
              <span></span>
            </div>
            <div class="details-block__card-text">
              <p>Фундамент – основа всей конструкции. От неё в большей степени зависит надёжность и срок службы дома. На что обращаем внимание при выборе основы:</p>
              <p>
                Особенности участка (геодезия, рельеф<br>
                Тяжесть постройки (стеновой материал, этажность, конфигурация).
              </p>
              <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="details-block__card-open show">Развернуть</a>
              <div class="var">
                <p>Основные виды фундаментов:</p>
                <ol>
                  <li>Ленточный (заглублённый и мелкозаглублёный). <br>
                  <br>
                  <br>
                  Хороший вариант для фундамента под деревянный дом;
                 </li>
                  <li>Монолитный – самый надёжный из всех;</li>
                  <li>Свайный или свайно-ростверковый.</li>
                </ol>
                <p>
                  Сделать правильный расчет, исходя из индивидуальных особенностей, может только специалист.
                </p>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="details-block__card-close hide">Свернуть</a>
              </div>
              <!-- /.var -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.details-block__card-text -->
          </div>
          <!-- /.details-block__card -->
          <div class="details-block__card">
            <h1 class="details-block__card-title">Крыши домов</h1>
            <!-- /.details-block__card-title -->
            <div class="details-block__card-img">
              <img src="img/details/img-2.jpg" alt="img-2">
              <span></span>
            </div>
            <div class="details-block__card-text">
              <p>Крыши могут быть: плоские, односкатные, многоскатные, купольные, мансардные.</p>
              <p>Выбор кровельного материала зависит от формы крыши. Наиболее часто используется мягкая кровля, металлочерепица (не подойдёт для купольной крыши), керамическая черепица.</p>
              <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="details-block__card-open show">Развернуть</a>
              <div class="var">
              <p>
                Монтаж, реконструкция, замена мягкой кровли дома, металочерепицы требуют
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                профессионализма и опыта. Особенно на многоскатных и мансардных крышах.
              </p>
              <p>Работая с нами, вы получаете:</p>
              <ol>
                <li>Гарантию от компании с большим опытом в строительстве;</li>
                <li>Высокий профессионализм мастеров;</li>
                <li>Работа с любой конфигурацией крыши и кровельным материалом;</li>
                <li>Демонтаж, монтаж, ремонт любой сложности.</li>
              </ol>
              <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="details-block__card-close hide">Свернуть</a>
              </div>
              <!-- /.var -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.details-block__card-text -->
          </div>
          <!-- /.details-block__card -->
          <div class="details-block__card">
            <h1 class="details-block__card-title">Водоснабжение и канализация</h1>
            <!-- /.details-block__card-title -->
            <div class="details-block__card-img">
              <img src="img/details/img-3.jpg" alt="img-3">
            </div>
            <div class="details-block__card-text">
              <p>Невозможно представить комфортного проживания без организованного водоснабжения и канализации. Подключение к центральным системам возможно только в редких случаях. Существует два способа по организации водоснабжения частного дома:</p>
              <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="details-block__card-open show">Развернуть</a>
              <div class="var">
                <ul>Обустройство артезианской скважины;</ul>
                <ul>Подача воды из колодца.</ul>
                <p>Для устройства канализации способа тоже<br><br> два:</p>
                <ul>
                  <li>Системы биологической очистки;</li>
                  <li>Септик на участке.</li>
                </ul>
                <p>Организовать удобства, привычные для городской жизни, в частном доме сегодня не представляют сложностей. Это возможно для любого дома, в независимости удалённости от города.</p>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="details-block__card-close hide">Свернуть</a>
              </div>
              <!-- /.var -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.details-block__card-text -->
          </div>
          <!-- /.details-block__card -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.details-block -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.container -->
    </section>
    <!-- /.details -->
```

```
 /* Разворачивание - сворачивание card service */
  $('.service-block__card-open .details-block__card-open').click(function(){
    $(this).next('.var').slideToggle('normal');
    return false;
  });
  $('.service-block__card-close .details-block__card-close').click(function(){
    $(this).parent('.var').slideToggle('normal');
  });
  $('.show').click(function() {
    $(this).hide().next('.var').slideDown().find('.hide').show();
  });
  $('.hide').click(function() {
    $(this).hide().closest('.var').slideUp().prev('.show').show();
  });
```

Comment: Из-за того, что вы задаёте `display: none` для кнопки свернуть, она теряет свою высоту. можно использовать вместо этого `visibility: visible/hidden` и `opacity`, таким образом блок будет занимать место на странице

Comment: нет, у вас там не overflow а текст при ховер белый ...а когда убираешь мышку он становится по умолчанию чёрный ...

Comment: @AndreyS, я сказал об ошибке не той, которую вы написали, а про первый блок, при полном открытии происходит дрыганье из-за того, что кнопка свернуть теряет свою высоту. Ну вообще, при анимации, лучше, чтобы блок оставался в потоке документа, не используйте `display: none`

Comment: Михаил Камахин спасибо! я думал над этим, но решил поправить это позже, сейчас черновой вариант делаю. 
MaximLensky не понимаю, да, текст меняется, но почему в верхней секции все нормально, а в нижней скрытый текст пропадает при наведении

Comment: @AndreyS задайте `body` `background-color: beige;` текст станет виден

Comment: да, точно, вижу, тогда вопрос, а почему hover не всю карточку подсвечивает?

Comment: @AndreyS Потому что вы сделали другую html структуру, а не как в прошлом слайдере

Comment: я тоже так думал, но я 2 раза все проверил, структура таже, даже сейчас еще раз посмотрел

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102990/discussion-between---and-andrey-s).

Comment: MaximLensky я этот код делал вчера весь день) с утра до ночи)) как это выкусить?)) мне жалко

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPD:**  добавил ко всем вариантам вендорные префиксы

Вот пример, как можно это сделать на JavaScript. **Вариант 1**

```js
let hide = document.querySelectorAll('.service-block__card-open');
let cardText = document.querySelectorAll('.service-block__card-text');
let hide__text = document.querySelectorAll('.hide__text');
let heightHide = [];

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

for (let i = 0; i < hide.length; i++) {
    heightHide.push(hide__text[i].offsetHeight);
    hide__text[i].style.height = '0px';
    hide[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
        cardText[i].classList.toggle('active');
        if (cardText[i].classList.contains('active')) {
            hide__text[i].style.height = heightHide[i] + 'px';;
        } else {
            hide__text[i].style.height = '0px';
        }
    });
}

});

let openElem = document.querySelectorAll('.service-block__card-open');
let openSpan = document.querySelectorAll('.openSpan');

for (let i = 0; i < openElem.length; i++) {
    openElem[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
        openElem[i].classList.toggle('active');
        if (openElem[i].classList.contains('active')) {
            openSpan[i].innerHTML = 'С';
        } else {
            openSpan[i].innerHTML = 'Раз';
        }
    });
}
```

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
 margin: 0;
 font-size: 16px;
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

img {
 display: block;
 max-width: 100%;
 height: auto;
}

.service-block__card {
 background-color: white;
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -o-flex;
 display: -webkit-box;
 display: -moz-box;
 display: -ms-flexbox;
 display: flex;
 -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
 -webkit-box-direction: normal;
 -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -moz-box-orient: vertical;
    -moz-box-direction: normal;
     -ms-flex-direction: column;
         flex-direction: column;
 max-width: 500px;
 margin: 10px auto 0;
 padding: 10px;
 -webkit-box-align: center;
 -webkit-align-items: center;
    -moz-box-align: center;
     -ms-flex-align: center;
         align-items: center;
 -webkit-transition: all .2s linear;
 -o-transition: all .2s linear;
 -moz-transition: all .2s linear;
 transition: all .2s linear;
}

.service-block__card-text {
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -o-flex;
 display: -webkit-box;
 display: -moz-box;
 display: -ms-flexbox;
 display: flex;
 -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
 -webkit-box-direction: normal;
 -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -moz-box-orient: vertical;
    -moz-box-direction: normal;
     -ms-flex-direction: column;
         flex-direction: column;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.hide__text {
 overflow: hidden;
 -webkit-transition: all .4s linear;
 -o-transition: all .4s linear;
 -moz-transition: all .4s linear;
 transition: all .4s linear;
}

.service-block__card-open {
 color: black;
 font-weight: bold;
 margin: 10px auto;
 font-size: 20px;
 cursor: pointer;
 -moz-user-select: none;
 -webkit-user-select: none;
     -ms-user-select: none;
         user-select: none;  
}
```

```html
<div class="service-block__card" id="card">
 <h1 class="service-block__card-title">Электрика</h1>
 <div class="service-block__card-img">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/800/500" alt="service-5">
  <span></span>
 </div>
 <div class="service-block__card-text">
  <p>Все понимают, что электрика – дело ответственное, сопряжённое с безопасностью и одновременно комфортом проживания.</p>
  <p>Электропроводка может быть устроена двумя способами:</p>
  <ul>
   <li>Закрытым. Прячется внутри стен и перекрытий, не портит внешнего вида. Наиболее часто применяется в жилых помещениях;</li>
   <li>Открытым. Располагается на поверхности стен и потолков, расположена в специальных коробах, может быть вмонтирована в плинтуса.</li>
  </ul>
  <a class="service-block__card-open"><span class="openSpan">Раз</span>вернуть</a>
  <div class="hide__text">
   <p>Электромонтаж в городской квартире и каменном загородном доме имеют много общего. Отличительные особенности для каменной загородной постройки:</p>
   <ol>
    <li>Обязательное устройство заземления;</li>
    <li>Устройство молниезащиты;</li>
    <li>Обязательное применение устройств защитного отключения.</li>
   </ol>
   <p>Монтаж электропроводки в деревянном доме имеет свои особенности. Сопряжено это с высокой пожароопасностью. Прежде всего, надо правильно рассчитать расчет нагрузок, исходя из него, подобрать кабель. Прокладка проводки внутри деревянных стен и перекрытий должна проводиться только в металлической трубе.</p>
   <p>Хотите жить комфортно? Ответственно относитесь к безопасности проживания?</p>
   <p>Выбирайте профессионалов!</p>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

**Вариант 2**
**Осторожно!** Я проверил, это не работает в `Firefox`, работает в `Google Chrome`, другие браузеры не смотрел, чтобы не схватить инсульт

```js
let hide = document.querySelectorAll('.service-block__card-open');
let cardText = document.querySelectorAll('.service-block__card-text');
let hide__text = document.querySelectorAll('.hide__text');
let heightHide = [];

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

for (let i = 0; i < hide.length; i++) {
    heightHide.push(hide__text[i].offsetHeight);
    hide__text[i].style.height = '0px';
    hide[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
        cardText[i].classList.toggle('active');
        if (cardText[i].classList.contains('active')) {
            hide__text[i].style.height = heightHide[i] + 'px';;
        } else {
            hide__text[i].style.height = '0px';
        }
    });
}

});

let openSpan = document.querySelectorAll('.openSpan');

for (let i = 0; i < openSpan.length; i++) {
    openSpan[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
        openSpan[i].classList.toggle('active');
    });
}
```

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
 margin: 0;
 font-size: 16px;
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

img {
 display: block;
 max-width: 100%;
 height: auto;
}

.service-block__card {
 background-color: white;
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -o-flex;
 display: -webkit-box;
 display: -moz-box;
 display: -ms-flexbox;
 display: flex;
 -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
 -webkit-box-direction: normal;
 -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -moz-box-orient: vertical;
    -moz-box-direction: normal;
     -ms-flex-direction: column;
         flex-direction: column;
 max-width: 500px;
 margin: 10px auto 0;
 padding: 10px;
 -webkit-box-align: center;
 -webkit-align-items: center;
    -moz-box-align: center;
     -ms-flex-align: center;
         align-items: center;
 -webkit-transition: all .2s linear;
 -o-transition: all .2s linear;
 -moz-transition: all .2s linear;
 transition: all .2s linear;
}

.service-block__card-text {
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -o-flex;
 display: -webkit-box;
 display: -moz-box;
 display: -ms-flexbox;
 display: flex;
 -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
 -webkit-box-direction: normal;
 -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -moz-box-orient: vertical;
    -moz-box-direction: normal;
     -ms-flex-direction: column;
         flex-direction: column;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.hide__text {
 overflow: hidden;
 -webkit-transition: all .4s linear;
 -o-transition: all .4s linear;
 -moz-transition: all .4s linear;
 transition: all .4s linear;
}

.service-block__card-open {
 color: black;
 font-weight: bold;
 margin: 10px auto;
 font-size: 20px;
 cursor: pointer;
 -moz-user-select: none;
 -webkit-user-select: none;
     -ms-user-select: none;
         user-select: none;  
 display: block;
}

:root {
 --atf: cubic-bezier(.58,-0.71,.41,1.55);
 --spanNum: 2rem; /* Размер текста .openSpan */
 --spanNumTopB: -webkit-calc(-1 * ( var(--spanNum)*1.2 ) );
 --spanNumTopB: -moz-calc(-1 * ( var(--spanNum)*1.2 ) );
 --spanNumTopB: calc(-1 * ( var(--spanNum)*1.2 ) );
 --spanNumLeftB: -webkit-calc( -1 * ( (var(--spanNum)*11)/160 ) );
 --spanNumLeftB: -moz-calc( -1 * ( (var(--spanNum)*11)/160 ) );
 --spanNumLeftB: calc( -1 * ( (var(--spanNum)*11)/160 ) );
 --spanNumSec: 1s; /* Время анимации */
}

.openSpan {
 display: -webkit-box;
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-box;
 display: -ms-flexbox;
 display: flex;
 font-size: var(--spanNum);
 font-family: sans-serif;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
    -moz-perspective: 1000px;
         perspective: 1000px;
 -moz-user-select: none;
 -webkit-user-select: none;
     -ms-user-select: none;
         user-select: none;
 cursor: pointer;
 max-height: var(--spanNum);
}

.openSpan .ab {
 position: relative;
 -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
         transform-style: preserve-3d;
 -webkit-transition: var(--spanNumSec) var(--atf) transform;
 -o-transition: var(--spanNumSec) var(--atf) transform;
 -moz-transition: var(--spanNumSec) var(--atf) transform;
 transition: var(--spanNumSec) var(--atf) transform;
}

.openSpan .ab > div {
 width: 100%;
 -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
         backface-visibility: hidden;
 text-align: end;
}

.openSpan .b {
 margin-top: var(--spanNumTopB);
 margin-left: var(--spanNumLeftB);
 -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg) rotateZ(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateX(180deg) rotateZ(90deg);
         transform: rotateX(180deg) rotateZ(90deg);
}

.openSpan .c {
 -webkit-transition: var(--spanNumSec) var(--atf) transform;
 -o-transition: var(--spanNumSec) var(--atf) transform;
 -moz-transition: var(--spanNumSec) var(--atf) transform;
 transition: var(--spanNumSec) var(--atf) transform;
}

.openSpan.active .ab{
 -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg) rotateZ(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateX(180deg) rotateZ(90deg);
         transform: rotateX(180deg) rotateZ(90deg);
}

.openSpan.active .c {
 -webkit-transform: rotateX(-360deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateX(-360deg);
         transform: rotateX(-360deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="service-block__card" id="card">
 <h1 class="service-block__card-title">Электрика</h1>
 <div class="service-block__card-img">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/800/500" alt="service-5">
  <span></span>
 </div>
 <div class="service-block__card-text">
  <p>Все понимают, что электрика – дело ответственное, сопряжённое с безопасностью и одновременно комфортом проживания.</p>
  <p>Электропроводка может быть устроена двумя способами:</p>
  <ul>
   <li>Закрытым. Прячется внутри стен и перекрытий, не портит внешнего вида. Наиболее часто применяется в жилых помещениях;</li>
   <li>Открытым. Располагается на поверхности стен и потолков, расположена в специальных коробах, может быть вмонтирована в плинтуса.</li>
  </ul>
  <a class="service-block__card-open">
   <span class="openSpan">
    <div class="ab">
     <div class="a">Раз</div>
     <div class="b">С</div>
    </div>
    <div class="c">вернуть</div>
   </span>
  </a>
  <div class="hide__text">
   <p>Электромонтаж в городской квартире и каменном загородном доме имеют много общего. Отличительные особенности для каменной загородной постройки:</p>
   <ol>
    <li>Обязательное устройство заземления;</li>
    <li>Устройство молниезащиты;</li>
    <li>Обязательное применение устройств защитного отключения.</li>
   </ol>
   <p>Монтаж электропроводки в деревянном доме имеет свои особенности. Сопряжено это с высокой пожароопасностью. Прежде всего, надо правильно рассчитать расчет нагрузок, исходя из него, подобрать кабель. Прокладка проводки внутри деревянных стен и перекрытий должна проводиться только в металлической трубе.</p>
   <p>Хотите жить комфортно? Ответственно относитесь к безопасности проживания?</p>
   <p>Выбирайте профессионалов!</p>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: работает в FF.... у меня по крайней мере

Comment: @MaximLensky у меня это так выглядит https://i.ibb.co/2cr1JTv/image.png

Comment: а как должно быть ?

Comment: @MaximLensky посмотрите в Google Chrome, там видно

Comment: Зачем столько префиксов? Неужели кто-то сидит на хроме 2012 года? И анимация эта совершенно не подходит сюда )