# Почему не реагирует transition height

Tags: javascript

Для элемента `.hide__text` не срабатывает transition, который я задал в css:

В JavaScript я задаю, что элементам `Развернуть` на странице задать слушатель события, который при клике будет скрывать/показывать текст

```css
.service-block__card-text.active .hide__text {
    height: 100%;
}
```

```js
let hide = document.querySelectorAll('.service-block__card-open');
let cardText = document.querySelectorAll('.service-block__card-text');

for (let i = 0; i < hide.length; i++) {
    hide[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
        cardText[i].classList.toggle('active');
    });
}
```

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
 margin: 0;
 font-size: 16px;
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.service-block__card {
 background-color: white;
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -o-flex;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 max-width: 500px;
 margin: 10px auto 0;
 padding: 10px;
 align-items: center;
}

.service-block__card-text {
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -o-flex;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
}

.hide__text {
 height: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
 transition: all 1s linear;
}

.service-block__card-text.active .hide__text {
 height: 100%;
}

.service-block__card-open {
 color: black;
 font-weight: bold;
 margin: 10px auto;
 font-size: 20px;
 cursor: pointer;
 -moz-user-select: none;
 user-select: none;  
}
```

```html
<div class="service-block__card">
 <h1 class="service-block__card-title">Электрика</h1>
 <div class="service-block__card-img">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/800/500" alt="service-5">
  <span></span>
 </div>
 <div class="service-block__card-text">
  <p>Все понимают, что электрика – дело ответственное, сопряжённое с безопасностью и одновременно комфортом проживания.</p>
  <p>Электропроводка может быть устроена двумя способами:</p>
  <ul>
   <li>Закрытым. Прячется внутри стен и перекрытий, не портит внешнего вида. Наиболее часто применяется в жилых помещениях;</li>
   <li>Открытым. Располагается на поверхности стен и потолков, расположена в специальных коробах, может быть вмонтирована в плинтуса.</li>
  </ul>
  <a class="service-block__card-open">Развернуть</a>
  <div class="hide__text">
   <p>Электромонтаж в городской квартире и каменном загородном доме имеют много общего. Отличительные особенности для каменной загородной постройки:</p>
   <ol>
    <li>Обязательное устройство заземления;</li>
    <li>Устройство молниезащиты;</li>
    <li>Обязательное применение устройств защитного отключения.</li>
   </ol>
   <p>Монтаж электропроводки в деревянном доме имеет свои особенности. Сопряжено это с высокой пожароопасностью. Прежде всего, надо правильно рассчитать расчет нагрузок, исходя из него, подобрать кабель. Прокладка проводки внутри деревянных стен и перекрытий должна проводиться только в металлической трубе.</p>
   <p>Хотите жить комфортно? Ответственно относитесь к безопасности проживания?</p>
   <p>Выбирайте профессионалов!</p>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Потому что там метод toggle , причем тут transition вообще

Comment: toggle просто меняет или удаляет класс, причём тут он?

Comment: А точно думал там просто toggle

Comment: https://mihinov.github.io/news/ Вот есть сайт, я его верстал, там есть кнопка открытия меню, я там элементам задавал класс .active через toggle и всё работало, элемент называется `.header__burger`

Comment: проблема в `100%` - если заменишь на пиксели начнет работать

Comment: @Grundy, да, вот недавно понял, я придумал: при загрузке страницы сначала узнавать изначальную высоту блока, потом скрывать его, и при клике показывать в пикселях

Comment: [How can I transition height: 0; to height: auto; using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3508605/2881286)

Comment: @МихаилКамахин А Jquerry не вариант использовать?

Comment: @ПоляковРоман я это уже решил на js, мой ответ на вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1066921/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d1%81-hover-%d1%8d%d1%84%d1%84%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%85%d0%b7-%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc/1067004#1067004

Comment: @МихаилКамахин просто смысл использовать translate c height , если slideToggle это тоже самое

Comment: @ПоляковРоман я это всё делаю на простом JavaScript, потому что я хочу уметь пользоваться языком JavaScript. Я не использовал translate, я создавал массив высот элементов и каждому элементу при клике задавал высоту в пикселях из массива

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`transition` не реагирует, потому что анимация `height` с 0 до 100% не работает, но анимация работает, если её задавать в пикселях.

```js
let hide = document.querySelectorAll('.service-block__card-open');
let cardText = document.querySelectorAll('.service-block__card-text');
let hide__text = document.querySelectorAll('.hide__text');
let heightHide = [];

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

for (let i = 0; i < hide.length; i++) {
    heightHide.push(hide__text[i].offsetHeight);
    hide__text[i].style.height = '0px';
    hide[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
        cardText[i].classList.toggle('active');
        if (cardText[i].classList.contains('active')) {
            hide__text[i].style.height = heightHide[i] + 'px';;
        } else {
            hide__text[i].style.height = '0px';
        }
    });
}

});

let openElem = document.querySelectorAll('.service-block__card-open');
let openSpan = document.querySelectorAll('.openSpan');

for (let i = 0; i < openElem.length; i++) {
    openElem[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
        openElem[i].classList.toggle('active');
        if (openElem[i].classList.contains('active')) {
            openSpan[i].innerHTML = 'С';
        } else {
            openSpan[i].innerHTML = 'Раз';
        }
    });
}
```

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
 margin: 0;
 font-size: 16px;
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

img {
 display: block;
 max-width: 100%;
 height: auto;
}

.service-block__card {
 background-color: white;
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -o-flex;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 max-width: 500px;
 margin: 10px auto 0;
 padding: 10px;
 align-items: center;
 transition: all .2s linear;
}

.service-block__card-text {
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -o-flex;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.hide__text {
 overflow: hidden;
 transition: all .4s linear;
}

.service-block__card-open {
 color: black;
 font-weight: bold;
 margin: 10px auto;
 font-size: 20px;
 cursor: pointer;
 -moz-user-select: none;
 user-select: none;  
}
```

```html
<div class="service-block__card" id="card">
 <h1 class="service-block__card-title">Электрика</h1>
 <div class="service-block__card-img">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/800/500" alt="service-5">
  <span></span>
 </div>
 <div class="service-block__card-text">
  <p>Все понимают, что электрика – дело ответственное, сопряжённое с безопасностью и одновременно комфортом проживания.</p>
  <p>Электропроводка может быть устроена двумя способами:</p>
  <ul>
   <li>Закрытым. Прячется внутри стен и перекрытий, не портит внешнего вида. Наиболее часто применяется в жилых помещениях;</li>
   <li>Открытым. Располагается на поверхности стен и потолков, расположена в специальных коробах, может быть вмонтирована в плинтуса.</li>
  </ul>
  <a class="service-block__card-open"><span class="openSpan">Раз</span>вернуть</a>
  <div class="hide__text">
   <p>Электромонтаж в городской квартире и каменном загородном доме имеют много общего. Отличительные особенности для каменной загородной постройки:</p>
   <ol>
    <li>Обязательное устройство заземления;</li>
    <li>Устройство молниезащиты;</li>
    <li>Обязательное применение устройств защитного отключения.</li>
   </ol>
   <p>Монтаж электропроводки в деревянном доме имеет свои особенности. Сопряжено это с высокой пожароопасностью. Прежде всего, надо правильно рассчитать расчет нагрузок, исходя из него, подобрать кабель. Прокладка проводки внутри деревянных стен и перекрытий должна проводиться только в металлической трубе.</p>
   <p>Хотите жить комфортно? Ответственно относитесь к безопасности проживания?</p>
   <p>Выбирайте профессионалов!</p>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```