# Не увеличивается высота блока

Tags: javascript

Программа при клике на `Развернуть` должна открывать и закрывать меню. Я хочу пройтись по всем элементам и раздать им слушатели для действий. При клике элемент должен увеличивать свою высоту до исходный если элемента есть класс `.active`, иначе высоту уменьшать до 0

```js
let hide = document.querySelectorAll('.service-block__card-open');
let cardText = document.querySelectorAll('.service-block__card-text');
let hide__text = document.querySelectorAll('.hide__text');
let heightHide = [];

for (let i = 0; i < hide.length; i++) {
    heightHide.push(hide__text[i].offsetHeight);
    console.log(heightHide);
    hide__text[i].style.height = '0px';
    hide[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
        cardText[i].classList.toggle('active');
        if (cardText[i].classList.contains('active')) {
            hide__text[i].style.height = heightHide[i];;
        } else {
            hide__text[i].style.height = '0px';
        }
    });
}
```

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
 margin: 0;
 font-size: 16px;
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

img {
 display: block;
 max-width: 100%;
 height: auto;
}

.service-block__card {
 background-color: white;
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -o-flex;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 max-width: 500px;
 margin: 10px auto 0;
 padding: 10px;
 align-items: center;
 transition: all .2s linear;
}

.service-block__card-text {
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -o-flex;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.hide__text {
 overflow: hidden;
 transition: all .4s linear;
}

.service-block__card-open {
 color: black;
 font-weight: bold;
 margin: 10px auto;
 font-size: 20px;
 cursor: pointer;
 -moz-user-select: none;
 user-select: none;  
}
```

```html
<div class="service-block__card" id="card">
 <h1 class="service-block__card-title">Электрика</h1>
 <div class="service-block__card-img">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/800/500" alt="service-5">
  <span></span>
 </div>
 <div class="service-block__card-text">
  <p>Все понимают, что электрика – дело ответственное, сопряжённое с безопасностью и одновременно комфортом проживания.</p>
  <p>Электропроводка может быть устроена двумя способами:</p>
  <ul>
   <li>Закрытым. Прячется внутри стен и перекрытий, не портит внешнего вида. Наиболее часто применяется в жилых помещениях;</li>
   <li>Открытым. Располагается на поверхности стен и потолков, расположена в специальных коробах, может быть вмонтирована в плинтуса.</li>
  </ul>
  <a class="service-block__card-open">Развернуть</a>
  <div class="hide__text">
   <p>Электромонтаж в городской квартире и каменном загородном доме имеют много общего. Отличительные особенности для каменной загородной постройки:</p>
   <ol>
    <li>Обязательное устройство заземления;</li>
    <li>Устройство молниезащиты;</li>
    <li>Обязательное применение устройств защитного отключения.</li>
   </ol>
   <p>Монтаж электропроводки в деревянном доме имеет свои особенности. Сопряжено это с высокой пожароопасностью. Прежде всего, надо правильно рассчитать расчет нагрузок, исходя из него, подобрать кабель. Прокладка проводки внутри деревянных стен и перекрытий должна проводиться только в металлической трубе.</p>
   <p>Хотите жить комфортно? Ответственно относитесь к безопасности проживания?</p>
   <p>Выбирайте профессионалов!</p>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

самостоятельный слушатель *запоминает* переменную `i`

```
hide[i].addEventListener('click', (e) => { // !!!
    cardText[i].classList.toggle('active');
    ...
        hide__text[i].style.height = 'unset';//heightHide[i];
```

```js
let hide = document.querySelectorAll('.service-block__card-open');
let cardText = document.querySelectorAll('.service-block__card-text');
let hide__text = document.querySelectorAll('.hide__text');
let heightHide = [];

for (let i = 0; i < hide.length; i++) {
    heightHide.push(hide__text[i].offsetHeight);
    hide[i].addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        cardText[i].classList.toggle('active');
        if (cardText[i].classList.contains('active')) {
            hide__text[i].style.height = 'unset';//heightHide[i];
        } else {
            hide__text[i].style.height = '0px';
        }
    });
}
```

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
 margin: 0;
 font-size: 16px;
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

img {
 display: block;
 max-width: 100%;
 height: auto;
}

.service-block__card {
 background-color: white;
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -o-flex;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 max-width: 500px;
 margin: 10px auto 0;
 padding: 10px;
 align-items: center;
 transition: all .2s linear;
}

.service-block__card-text {
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -o-flex;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.hide__text {
 overflow: hidden;
 transition: all .4s linear;
 display: inline-block;
 height: 0px;
}

.service-block__card-open {
 color: black;
 font-weight: bold;
 margin: 10px auto;
 font-size: 20px;
 cursor: pointer;
 -moz-user-select: none;
 user-select: none;  
}
```

```html
<div class="service-block__card" id="card">
 <h1 class="service-block__card-title">Электрика</h1>
 <div class="service-block__card-img">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/800/500" alt="service-5">
  <span></span>
 </div>
 <div class="service-block__card-text">
  <p>Все понимают, что электрика – дело ответственное, сопряжённое с безопасностью и одновременно комфортом проживания.</p>
  <p>Электропроводка может быть устроена двумя способами:</p>
  <ul>
   <li>Закрытым. Прячется внутри стен и перекрытий, не портит внешнего вида. Наиболее часто применяется в жилых помещениях;</li>
   <li>Открытым. Располагается на поверхности стен и потолков, расположена в специальных коробах, может быть вмонтирована в плинтуса.</li>
  </ul>
  <a class="service-block__card-open">Развернуть</a>
  <div class="hide__text">
   <p>Электромонтаж в городской квартире и каменном загородном доме имеют много общего. Отличительные особенности для каменной загородной постройки:</p>
   <ol>
    <li>Обязательное устройство заземления;</li>
    <li>Устройство молниезащиты;</li>
    <li>Обязательное применение устройств защитного отключения.</li>
   </ol>
   <p>Монтаж электропроводки в деревянном доме имеет свои особенности. Сопряжено это с высокой пожароопасностью. Прежде всего, надо правильно рассчитать расчет нагрузок, исходя из него, подобрать кабель. Прокладка проводки внутри деревянных стен и перекрытий должна проводиться только в металлической трубе.</p>
   <p>Хотите жить комфортно? Ответственно относитесь к безопасности проживания?</p>
   <p>Выбирайте профессионалов!</p>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Не надо назначать `style.height`. Опишите [не]видимое состояние в отдельном классе и убирайте/добавляйте его.

Comment: Мне нужна анимация, поэтому я получаю исходную высоту элемента, `unset` не подходит

Comment: @МихаилКамахин основная ошибка у Вас - `(i) => {`

Comment: это я уже пробовал во время отчаяния, когда у меня не получалось работать с высотой ничего, убрал это, у меня сейчас почему-то просто не открывается

Comment: @МихаилКамахин Не надо назначать `style.height`. Опишите [не]видимое состояние в отдельном классе и убирайте/добавляйте его.

Comment: Из-за этого поста я решил таким способом делать. Я не понимаю, как это сделать просто добавляя/удаляя класс, анимируя это
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1066961/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82-transition-height

Comment: О боже, я просто не добавил слово 'px', к высоте, извините!

Comment: Igor, если у вас есть решение без этого(моего) садизма, покажите его, я не понял как это анимировать просто задавая класс